# Google OAuth - Incremental scopes need new refresh token?

Tags: google-oauth

Just a quick question and I haven't been able to find this answered anywhere.

If I have a user with a Refresh Token with scope x and I need to add scope y, will they be issued a new refresh token or do I keep their existing refresh token.

My expectation is that no new Refresh Token is generated, it is the access token which will have the new scope and I use the existing Refresh Token to get the new access token on the server.

Is my understanding correct here?